# Genymotion does not want to star

Tags: android, linux, emulation

I'm trying to emulate android in Genymotion, but whenever I open it, it appears

> "In order to work, Genymotion requires VirtualBox to be installed on your computer. You can download the latest version of VirtualBox from www.virtualbox.org/wiki/ Downloads. "

I own the latest version of Virtual Box, but I still do not know why the error occurs.

Comment: I am curious why not go with Android Studio/Android Emulator? it there any particular feature you needed lacking in android studio. GenyMotion might be tied to a particular vbox version. In order to work with vbox, some plugin dll files are needed, which heavily depends on vbox versions.

Answer (score 0):

Does your VirtualBox work? Do you have HyperV enabled? If so, make sure Hyper-V is disabled.

Also, in Genymotion settings, make sure your VirtualBox path to Virtual Devices is set to a valid folder.